# Recording RTSP-Stream with avconv and segmentation: incorrect codec parameters

Tags: video, vlc, rtsp, codec, avconv

I am trying to record an RTSP-Stream from a PoE IP-camera (Lupusnet LE932) using the tool avconv (version v10_alpha2-128-g77bb000). With the VLC Media Player 2.1.4, this RTSP-stream works without any problems. I can view it and record it. Now I wanted to use segmentation (recording the video in splitted files, for example one file for every hour), so I switched to avconv.

This is the command I am using:

```
    avconv -i rtsp://192.168.1.41/ -c copy -map 0 -f segment
    -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "capture-%03d.mp4"
```

In the webcam user interface it's possible to change the video format from H.264 to MP4, which I did, but it does not help.

So these are the resulting error messages:

```
    [rtsp @ 0153af00] max_analyze_duration reached
    [rtsp @ 0153af00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

And:

```
    [mp4 @ 015e67e0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format
    requires global headers
    [mp4 @ 015e67e0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format
    requires global headers
    [mp4 @ 015e67e0] track 1: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in
    container
```

My question: **Why is the recording of the stream working with VLC but not with avconv? And what is meant with these error messages?** (I'm a complete beginner)